# A faster implementation of AcceptChanges?

Tags: vb.net, .net-datatable

So I started wondering why it takes 3.5 seconds to `AcceptChanges` for one changed record in a large `DataTable`. I wrote another implementation of `AcceptChanges` (VB.NET) - `Me` is a `DataTable` here:

```vb
Public Shadows Sub AcceptChanges()
  'this way AcceptChanges is 35 to 700 faster than Microsoft's way
  '35 is a speed factor when all rows were changed, and 700 is when a few
  'Tested on sets of 13K and 65K records
  Dim updatedRows() As DataRow = Me.Select(Nothing, Nothing, _
    DataViewRowState.Added Or DataViewRowState.Deleted Or _
    DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent Or DataViewRowState.ModifiedOriginal)
  For Each row As DataRow In updatedRows
    row.AcceptChanges()
  Next
End Sub
```

It appears to be from 35 to 700 times faster than Microsoft's implementation. Did I just uncover/solve a great mystery of ADO.NET, or am I missing something here?

Comment: I am not fluent in VB, but there must be a reason why they put _two_ try clauses in the function. My guess is that your function is more efficient but less robust.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: there isn't anything VB-specific in the above code. Do you have trouble reading it? I can translate into C# for you, if you want. Wrapping it into a Try clause will not decrease performance. Main side of my question is when I will regret about changing to this implementation, instead of Microsoft's AcceptChanges. Every single test I did, performance wise, points that I am on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to answer your question by looking at the [`DataTable.AcceptChanges` source code](http://typedescriptor.net/browse/members/388932-System.Data.DataTable.AcceptChanges%28%29).

As you can see they copy all `DataRow` objects into new array before iterating them. I suspect that your code will work incorrectly when rows are deleted (accepting changes for deleted rows means removing them from `DataTable`), most likely you'll get exception since it's not allowed to change collection while iterating it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. `Me.Select` returns an array of `DataRow`, which is not the original `DataRows` collection. So I cannot see a problem here.

Comment: A good question would be when `SuspendIndexEvents` and `RestoreIndexEvents` would play a part (i.e. make it faster than my implementation), if ever.